# Linker error for Raspberry Crosscompile

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, linker-errors, cross-compiling

So I installed the toolchain given by raspberry which works good , I managed to compile the library used by the GUI

I have installed all dependancies for the GUI using

`xapt -a armhf -m [packet]`

But when the linker has to link all librairies it give me the following error and I'm stuck.

`arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld: pkcs11dialogs.o: undefined reference to symbol '_Znwj@@GLIBCXX_3.4'
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line`

Any help will be very appreciate !

Merci !

Comment: Are you sure you're not building C++ code? Try using `g++` instead of `gcc`.

Comment: Same issue  `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -g -O2 -pipe -mcpu=arm1176jzf-s -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard -I. -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-release-2.8 -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/wx-2.8 -D_REENTRANT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread -lcrypto -c pkcs11dialogs.cpp -o pkcs11dialogs.o` for compiler

Comment: `arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld -rpath-link=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib -L/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib -L /tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/lib -L/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib -pthread -lwx_gtk2u_xrc-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_html-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_qa-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_adv-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_core-2.8 -lwx_baseu_xml-2.8 -lwx_baseu_net-2.8 -lwx_baseu-2.8  -lcrypto  -o idprimepkcs11gui pkcs11dialogs.o idprimepkcs11gui.o` For linker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're compiling C++ code and not C. C++ needs a runtime support library, the native GCC library is called libstdc++ and you need to link with that.

It's very easy to do: Use the `g++` (`arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++` in your case) frontend program to link as well as compile., it will automatically add the C++ runtime library. Or add it manually to your linker command.

Comment: It works ! thank's a lot ! I got another issue on the rPi my GUI said Illegal instruction but `file gui` tell me `ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=0x545a561f362081f337cfa0d5a31571dbbae772b3, not stripped`